# Setting TreeView ForeColor using C#

Tags: c#, winforms, treeview

I have a treeview that when the user interacts with individual nodes, the colours change. The code is:

```
treeview.selectednode.forecolor = color.red;
```

When the user presses a button, I want the whole set of nodes to change to black for example. So I code as such:

```
treeview.forecolor = color.black;
```

It works fine, except for the nodes that I have previously changed to red. Is there a way to get around this?

Comment: Does that actually compile? The name of the property is *[ForeColor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.forecolor.aspx)*, not *forecolor*. Also, it is supposed to be *[Color.Black](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.color.black.aspx)*, not *color.black*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this recursive function:

```
private void treeView1_NodeMouseClick(object sender, TreeNodeMouseClickEventArgs e)
{
    (sender as TreeView).SelectedNode.ForeColor = Color.Red;
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    foreach (TreeNode tn in treeView1.Nodes)
    {
        tn.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        ColorNodes(tn);
    }
}

private void ColorNodes(TreeNode t)
{
    foreach (TreeNode tn in t.Nodes)
    {
        tn.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
        ColorNodes(tn);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks - Did think of that, but if I have a Treeview of several hundred or thousand nodes, how efficient would this scale?  Thanks again.

Comment: I think i'm going to do this, but asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

Keep a reference to the previously selected node, turn it into black whenever you change  treeview to black.

Comment: Can't do that.....there are instances where the treeview is loaded with the red nodes. Thanks anyway.